# Detecting the IE "Ignore colors specified on webpages" setting state

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, accessibility

There is an accessibility option ("Ignore colors specified on webpages") in IE that removes all of the CSS color/background-colors from a webpage in order to make it easier to view for some users.

This can cause issues by removing helpful images that simply cannot be output in the foreground.

Does anyone know if there is a way to detect the state of this setting in an end-users browser?

Ultimately it could be used to display alternative styles depending on the state of this setting, so if it can be detected using JS it would be perfect.

However, I realise that it is a long shot as allowing web pages to detect browser settings could open up security holes! But any thoughts on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as far as i know there is no way to do it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I suspected as much! I will continue searching for a solution as this would make it a great deal easier to produce user friendly, accessible web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test a given element with *getComputedStyle*; this will not save you with custom css (if the user has an override css defined in accessibility settings), but with stripped colors it does work (though it's still a hack).

A jQuery example follows:

```
<div id="example" style="background-color:lime;width:40px;height:40px;border:2px solid #000;"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
    alert($("#example").css("backgroundColor"));
});
</script>
```

This will give you white (255,255,255) with accessible colors and the appropriate lime (0,255,0) with stripped colors - this shall get you started with this detection, should you decide to use it.

Comment: Nice! I have done a few quick tests and JS does indeed return a background-color value of '#ffffff' or 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' when the "ignore colours" settings is enabled. Naturally in it's current form this will only work when the user has the setting enabled before they load the page - but I can work on that. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I can't find the link I was looking for, but the following link will get you started: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css-system

Best thing about it is you don't need Javascript.

Comment: i don't see how this enables you to detect the color-override??

Comment: This method automatically uses the user's settings vs detecting.

Comment: 1) this is deprecated 2) The OP does not want to use usersettings, he wants to detect IF the user overrides the normal settings.