# How to detect/target "Ignore colors specified on webpages" setting in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I need to style an element if IE's "ignore colors specified on webpages" is enabled but I didn't find a way to do so.

There seems to be only one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855917/detecting-the-ie-ignore-colors-specified-on-webpages-setting-state) (that I know of) that tests if an element's computed background style returns 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' or '#fff' if this mode is enabled, but that doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to detect this mode with CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: IE hasn't been updated since 2016, how would that detection suddenly cease working?

Comment: Maybe the following link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855917/detecting-the-ie-ignore-colors-specified-on-webpages-setting-state

Comment: I have tested the solution in the thread and it works for me. The testing result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3zfF.png) if I enable the setting. How does it not work for you? It returns other value or anything else? Have you included the jQuery library? Besides, what is your IE version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me detect the ignore color mode:

```
(function (W, $) {
    'use strict';

    var $body = $("body")
        , interval = $body.data("ignore-color-int") || 4000
        , debug = W.location.href.match(/debug=1/) || $body.data("debug")
        , C = W.console
        , D = C && debug
        ;

    function detect_ignore_color() {

        var hcmclass = "no-ignore-color"
            , $hcm = $("<p style='position:absolute;top:0;left:-999px;background-color:#878787;'>T</p>")
            , testcolor = $hcm.css("background-color").toLowerCase()
            ;

        $.isIgnoreColor = (testcolor !== "#878787" && testcolor !== "rgb(135, 135, 135)");

        if ($.isIgnoreColor) {
            hcmclass = "ignore-color";
            var accessibleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.accessible-hidden-text');

            for (var i = 0; i < accessibleElements.length; i++) {
                accessibleElements[i].style.opacity = 1;
            }
        }

        $body.removeClass('ignore-color no-ignore-color').addClass(hcmclass);

        D && C.log('> ', interval, hcmclass);
    }

    $(W).resize(detect_ignore_color);

    $(function () {
        detect_ignore_color();

        W.setInterval(detect_ignore_color, interval);
    });

}(window, jQuery));
```